# Stylesheet Not being applied to html because of it's mime type

Tags: html, css, express, filesystems

I'm getting an error saying that it can't add my stylesheet because of it's mime type. I suspect it has something to do with the path i'm giving it but not completely sure

I tried changing the file path and by clicking the link in visual studio code it will take me to the css stylesheet but not on my localhost.

```
Error 

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8081/assets/css/stylesheet.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled
```

```
Link Source

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/stylesheet.css">
```

```
File System

public|-
  assets|-
       css|-
         -stylesheet.css
  index.html    

server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `type="text/css"` in the link tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the stylesheet cannot be found. The `text/html` MIME type is the result of the 404 page (which is HTML).

Changing your link to the following by removing the `css` folder level will fix the problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheet.css">
```

Comment: I made a mistake and didn't add the css folder to the question. Which is in my actual file path I updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I had the middleware set up incorrect.